# Selenium/Python: Error click a button whose address is with JavaScript, onclick

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, onclick, click

I have been stuck on trying to click the href="javascript:;" on a page using selenium with python.

The relevant HTML code is:

```html
<tr>
  <td class="Sun out">24</td>
  <td class=" out">25</td>
  <td class=" out">26</td>
  <td class=" out">27</td>
  <td class=" out">28</td>
  <td id="CellPlayDate0" class=" able"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="fnSelectPlayDate(0, '20171229')">29</a></td>
  <td id="CellPlayDate1" class=" able"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="fnSelectPlayDate(1, '20171230')">30</a></td>
</tr>
```

For code, I have:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="CellPlayDate0"]').click()
```

The corresponding error message is:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

I think that the elements is list, so i tried as below

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@id="CellPlayDate1"]')[0].click()
```

However, another error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I think there is another method to click a button(javascript,onclick). However, I am the very beginner of selenium, so i have no idea.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems `browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="CellPlayDate0"]')` returns a `list` of elements.

You need to pick an element and create click event may be like

`browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="CellPlayDate0"]')[0].click()`

Comment: I've tried that. However, there is an IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: In that case your xpath expression `'//*[@id="CellPlayDate0"]'` does not match any `id` in the html page.

Comment: Actually, I copy that html code in a page using copy xpath

Comment: Could you please edit the original question with snippet of html page?

Comment: Could you check again

Comment: Is there a chance, that this html gets loaded into html using javascript? You may need to check for page fully loaded before doing `click()` in that case.

Comment: When i tried it after enough time for load, the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

As per your code block you have :

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="CellPlayDate0"]').click()
```

Which instead of an `WebElement` returns a `List`. Hence when you try to click on the `List` you see the error as `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`

Solution would be either to change the method `find_elements_by_xpath` to `find_element_by_id` or to construct an unique `xpath` as follows:

- As the `WebElement` have a `id`:

  ```
  browser.find_elements_by_id("CellPlayDate0').click()
  ```
- Construct an `xpath`:

  ```
  browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@id='CellPlayDate0']").click()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There problem here is you're calling `click()` on a list of `<td>` instead of the `<a>` anchor which actually has the click you wanted. Try this instead:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CellPlayDate0"]/a').click()
```

Notice the use of `find_element_by_xpath` instead of `find_element[s]_by_xpath`? Or with css:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#CellPlayDate0 a').click()
```

Comment: Still, there is the same error, AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

First, the xpath expression returns a list as the other answers have pointed out. Python lists don't have a click method, the returned elements do.

Second, your xpath expression *isn't actually finding anything*. It's returning an empty list of no matches, which is why you're getting the index out of range error.

What you probably want is this:

```
for elem in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="CellPlayDate0"]'):
    elem.click()
```

Note that you'll still need to tweak the xpath string to actually match something on the page.

Comment: There is no error. However, the button is not clicked.